# HTML not printing the full name returned by flask

Tags: html, flask, web-development-server

I want to know why the input filed is displaying only Varun not Varun Achar

Following is the code of my HTML page.

```
{%if users%}
  <label >
    Patient ID
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="PID" value={{  users[1]  }}>
  <label >
    Patient Name:
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="pname" value={{  users[2]  }} />   
{%endif%}
```

Here in command prompt its printing Varun Achar but in the front HTML input field, it's printing only `Varun`.

Please help with this issue

Comment: Pls format ur code properly and show ur python code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap that `value` with double quotes.

```
{%if users%}
  <label>
    Patient ID
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="PID" value= "{{users[1]}}">
  <label>
    Patient Name:
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="pname" value="{{users[2]}}"/>
{%endif%}
```